# PHP Simple Insert Issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, insert

I cannot figure out what the issue is with my PHP but the INSERT function seems to fail at all times.  I have the correct table rows listed but there could just be a simple syntax issue.  If that code is needed, I can supply it also. Here's my PHP and database structure:

[image]

```
  <?php  
 $con = mysql_connect('***','***','***');  
    if (!$con)  
{  
    echo "Failed to make connection.";  
    exit;  
}  
$db = mysql_select_db('***');  
if (!$db)  
{  
    echo "Failed to select db.";  
    exit;  
}  
$username   = $_POST['username'];  
$password   = $_POST['password'];  
$name      = $_POST['name'];  
$email      = $_POST['email'];  
$sql        = "SELECT username,email FROM Users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' OR email = '" . $email . "'";  
$query      = mysql_query($sql);  
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)  
{  
    echo "That username or email already exists";  
}  
else  
{  
    $insert = "INSERT INTO Users(username,password,name,email) VALUES ('" . $username . "','" . $password . "','" . $name . "','" . $email . "')";  
    $query  = mysql_query($insert);  
    if ($query)  
    {  
        echo "Thanks for registering. You may now login.";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        echo "Insert failed";  
    }  
}  
?>
```

Comment: what is the mysql error

Comment: is the id is auto incrementing?

Comment: Also your script is full of SQL injection vulnerabilities, read http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php :)

Comment: what I always do in this situation: after `$insert` put `echo $insert`. it will display your mysql query. copy/paste this query in phpmyadmin and see which error is. then post it here, so it will be easier to see where the problem is

Comment: Not directly related to solving your problem, but the use of mysql_* functions are really... well, not recommended. Have a look at mysqli_*, or better yet - PDO. :)

Comment: General Info : Not a single(popular one) website need login just after registration so why are you doing that

Comment: It WAS the Auto Incrementing issue!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw the error if the query fails so you can see what's happening. Take this out before you go live though.

```
$query = mysql_query($insert);
if (!$query) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "Thanks for registering. You may now login.";
}
```

Also a couple of suggestions for your login form. Escape the stuff your inputting into your database using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php. I'd also recommend finding a good regex to validate the email before you save it. And even hashing the password at a minimum.

Comment: there are filters in php then why you want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Is it possible to show a few examples of sanitizing the data with my current script above?

Comment: $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

I also recommend using mysqli...http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Would you know how to rewrite this in MySQLi?  I'm not having much luck replicating this script.

Answer (score 1):

Might be that you dont have a space in between Users and "(".
Also, is your table with a capital letter.
Maybe the table has some prefixes?

Comment: Spaces around delimiter characters are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but it *may* be as simple as this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Users(username,password,name,email) VALUES ('$username','$password','$name','$email')";
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to rewrite this script in Mysqli?